# Obtaining the SQL Server 2005 Report Builder XSD

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, xsd, reportingservices-2005, reportbuilder

I've managed to obtain the report definition schema for SQL Server 2005, but cannot find the `xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner"` schema anywhere.

Is it part of the 2005 install buried somewhere? The reason I ask is because I've recently started writing RDL files for SQL Reporting Services. I'd like to be able to validate both schemas and get autocompletion working (I'm using Eclipse mostly). Any Ideas on how I can get ahold of this xsd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just an XML namespace - there's no physical representation of that, really. The `rd` namespace is part of the report definition stuff - should be in your XSD already.

Comment: I kind of poured through the xsd and didn't find any sign of it. I know that essentially these are just for the benefit of the report builder application and have nothing to do with whether the report runs or not, but I'd like to be able to see what that Application is looking for....

Comment: @npeterson: you just need to search for the XML namespace itself - the prefix used is irrelevant. That XML namespace should be in the report server XSD I believe (maybe using a different or no prefix at all)